# In tensor notation in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, what is that character that looks like a 3?

Tags: tensors

For example, saying that $T$ is a k-tensor one might see $T\in 3^k(V)$, of course it's not actually a  3.  It looks somewhat like Fraktur font Z: $\frak{Z}$.  I couldn't detexify it, and it doesn't appear to be a standard notation for the set of tensors.  Other resources seem to just use $T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's fraktur I: $\mathfrak{I}$.  I don't think this is standard.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought it was a script T, as is used in John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (though admittedly for tensor *fields*).

Comment: It doesn't look like \mathfrak{T} or \mathcal{T}.  But I guess these things aren't necessarily set in stone.

Comment: Isn't there a \mathscr font?  Maybe it's \mathscr{T}?